# Where should a script placed for client-server communication PVE?

Tags: sockets, server, virtual-machine, virtualenv, proxmox

ive been writing a script in Python (3.0) to communicate with a server of our company. The client is supposed to pull a JSON file and read in out  in the CL... at first.
We got Proxmox VE and im completly new into Network Engineering and virtual environment but pretty good at coding, so i hope somebody can help me out :)

I just see the Datacenter and some VM's under it in our Proxmox Manager.
I have following question:

-Where am i supposed to place the script and how do i run it then?

Should  i be lucky and heres a Proxmox geek, how can i create a API key? I found the function to create tokens, but  i cant  find keys.

Greeting Rxven.

Ive done reasearches.